# How to create a triangular tip with outline on top of an HTML element with Pure CSS?

Tags: html, css

[image]

You may have probably seen this type of boxes with a triangular arrow tip on Facebook, Google, Twitter, etc. Fortunately, I've also created one with pure CSS.

Here is the code:

> HTML :

```
<div class="box"><h3>This box contains a triangular arrow tip on top of it.</h3></div>
```

> CSS :

```
.box { position: relative; background: #fff; color: #000; padding: 8px; border: 1px solid #ccc; }

.box:after {content: ""; position: absolute; display: block; width: 0; top: -15px; right: auto; bottom: auto; left: 5px; border-width: 0 10px 15px; border-style: solid; border-color: #fff transparent; }
```

You can see that the triangular tip is pure white color. And if you study the CSS you'll see that the white color of the tip is actually the color of the border.

Now what I'm looking for is a (gray coloured, for example) border or outline on the surface of the triangular tip. Because the color of the tip comes from the border, I can't use a second border because there is no such thing. I've tried outline but it doesn't seem to work. Any help how to do this with pure CSS?

Comment: You can't add an outline to the border.

Comment: `content: '\u25bc;'`, which in most web fonts is a downwards solid arrow?

Comment: Then how to do it? @BenM

Comment: @Adil Np, I think it makes the question clearer and I hope it's answered faster :)

Comment: what about a box shadow?

Comment: Box shadow works for boxes, not for borders. I've already tried it though. @PatrickJamesMcDougle

Comment: A nice variety of solutions has turned up so far: CSS border triangles, unicode up arrows, and applying a CSS3 2D transform to rotate a square with 2 borders.

Answer (score 5):

Make use of the `:before` pseudo-element to place a similar arrow behind the first one.

This is the technique used on http://cssarrowplease.com.

[See it in action based on your example](http://jsfiddle.net/SJ797/).

```
.box:before {
    content:"";
    position: absolute;
    display: block;
    width: 0;
    top: -16px;
    right: auto;
    bottom: auto;
    left: 3px;
    border-width: 0 12px 17px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: #ccc transparent;
    z-index: -1;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Don't use borders to create the triangle. Simply use a pseudo-element on which you apply a CSS transform.

## [*DEMO*](http://codepen.io/thebabydino/pen/oJCze)

Result:

[image: result]

**HTML**:

```
<ul class='drop-down'>
  <li><a href='#'>Suggestions</a></li>
  <li><a href='#'>Friends (8)</a></li>
  <li><a href='#'>Friend Requests</a></li>
  <li><a href='#'>My Requests</a></li>
  <li><a href='#'>People I blocked</a></li>
</ul>
```

Relevant **CSS**:

```
.drop-down {
  position: relative;
  border: solid 1px #ccc;
  background: white;
}
.drop-down:before {
  position: absolute;
  top: -.56em; left: 1em;
  border-left: solid 1px #ccc;
  border-top: solid 1px #ccc;
  width: 1em; height: 1em;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  background: inherit;
  content: '';
}

/* variations */
.drop-down:first-child:before {
  transform: rotate(60deg) skewX(30deg) scaleY(.866);
}
.drop-down:nth-child(3):before {
  border-right: solid 1px #ccc;
  border-left: none;
  transform: rotate(-60deg) skewY(30deg) scaleX(.866);
}
```

Comment: This seems like a more-elegant solution than CSS border triangles and unicode up arrows (as long as support for IE8 or earlier isn't required). From what I've observed, it also renders the best (as far as antialiasing). And it only requires a single pseudeo-element (freeing one up for some other purpose, if necessary).

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with with the UTF-8 "up arrow" and a bit of absolute positioning and a text shadow:

Your container:

```
.boxArrow {
    margin-top:30px;
    height:100px;
    width:100px;    
    border:1px solid #000000;
    position:relative;
}
```

The arrow:

```
.boxArrow:before {
    content: "\25B2";
    font-size:16px;
    color:#ffffff;
    position:absolute;
    top:-15px;
    left:30px;
    text-shadow: -1px 0 black, 0 1px white, 1px 0 black, 0 -1px black;
}
```

Comment: Wow, I never knew of these "\25B2" type of things before. Thanks a lot! Are there codes for "left arrow" and "right arrow" and "down arrow" too?

Answer (score 0):

For simplicity, easy and fast work, you can use jQuery UI : http://jqueryui.com/tooltip/#custom-style